# Get x y plots in matplotlib from columns x and y

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to put x and y into columns. Then access the sub plots from the columns?

```
import numpy as np #import numpy

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #import matplotlib



x = np.array([0,0,4,0])  #array x on the x axis with co-ordinates

y = np.array([0,3,3,0])#array y on the y axis with co-ordinates



plt.figure()

plt.plot(x, y, 'blue')  #display triangle in blue



plt.show() #show triangle`
```

Comment: The intent of the question is vague and unclear. If you want to process the data before drawing the graph, you can get the data in the following way. `lines, = plt.plot(x, y, 'blue');l = lines.get_data();print(l)`

Comment: you reference "plots" and "both plots" which sounds like there are 2 plots, but i only see code for 1 plot

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness

Comment: do you mean pandas dataframe columns? `import pandas as pd; df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})`

Comment: Hi tdy I figured out a solution..I meant import mathoplib as plt..then plot by column data..not using dataframes.but thanks for the suggestion